# Implementing a "table" in C#

Tags: c#

I'm working on    Etp (employee timetabling problem) problem  using  RSSHC  algorithem  from the hill climbing 
family .

From this matter I need to create a "table "  like this:

```
    s1   s2   s3   s4   s5 S6   
------
e1  5                   8       
e2       3    4     
e3
e4
e5
```

The  rows represent  the  employees (employee number); 
the columns  represent the  the shift (shift ID)
and the value represent the  task number (task ID).
All those taken from the database. 
On this table  I will need to switch tasks between employees 
and run constraint checks   every time  there is a switch. 
Is there  any  datatype  that will support this layout (I'm new at C#)?
Or maybe it would be  better to do it  via   stored proc  on
my database?

The  constraints  will be calculated  via  'cost function'
and  give  a penalty point  for every constraint violation. 
For example:

e2  doing   task 2  on S2 and task 4 on S3 
maybe e2 can't do task 2 (abilities)
or do not have enough workload (I need to look on e2 vector and count that )
or maybe according to my rules  an employee can't do 2 shifts in a row. 
(I will need to look for values on s1 and s3)
Perhaps the employee   can't work today (preference)
(I will need to check that ).
That's  the  main constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your shiftIDs are known you could create an class like:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int S1 { get; set; }
    public int S2 { get; set; }
    public int S3 { get; set; }
    public int S4 { get; set; }
}
```

This class would be put into an `List<Employee>`. This list would then be put into a `BindingSource.DataSource` and last but not least you put this into a `DataTable.DataSource`.

With this you can simply make any changes within the DataGrid, which will directly reflected into your List.

Comment: i need those   integer  names like  s1   to be  created  dynamicly according to the  shift names  or ID  number  in the database

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) or a [multidimensional array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), depending on your performance requirements.